# Javascript chaining asign variable

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Can someone help me ?

```js
var { id } = [response] = [{ id: 1 }];

console.log(id)
```

Output : undefined,
Expected output : 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of an assignment expression is always the value that was assigned (i.e. an array in your case).

```js
var [{id}] = [response] = [{id : 1}]

console.log(id)
```

Note that this will create a global `response` variable if the variable isn't declared yet (or throws an error in strict mode).

It might be easier to understand if you performed this in two steps:

```
var [response] = [{id: 1}];
var {id} = response;
```

Comment: …and for the "single-line feeling" you can use `var [response] = …, {id} = response;`